# Python Script not Running - Has to be something simple

Tags: python, python-2.7, fedora-21

OS:  Fedora 21
Python:  2.7.6

I run a python script as root or using sudo it runs fine.  If I run it as just the user I get the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/user/dev_ad_list.py", line 12, in 
>      import ldap
>   ImportError: No module named ldap

selinux=disabled   --  What other security is preventing a user from running a python script that imports ldap

Comment: Have you installed a library that provides an ldap module? It's not part of the stdlib.

Comment: Try printing out your path as a user and as sudo. **import sys  for p in sys.path: print p**.  Also **print ldap.__file__**.   Assess path differences.  Python itself may also be different.

Comment: TY Peyret.  That's it:   'which python' = ~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python

Answer (score 1):

If it works fine under `sudo`, it simply sounds like a file access issue.

A quick fix for this would be to run something along the lines of:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rX /usr/lib/python2.7
```

But you may wish to be more specific with the directory (or even file) that you actually apply this to.

Answer (score 0):

Path to python was different than other user.  User was pointing to canopy.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick and intuitive responses.